# custom table to ForeignKey

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I need to custom table models to ForeignKey

```
employee_id = models.ForeignKey(ExternalDatabase)
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I need to fetch employee_id from old table that's not Django models

How to fetch *ExternalDatabase* by raw query and shown its in admin list like ForeignKey fields

Comment: make a Django model for it https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/legacy-databases/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django currently doesn't support relations between two databases. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev//topics/db/multi-db/#limitations-of-multiple-databases